# How can I make a 48x microscope with combination of lenses?

Tags: design, optics

As part of a project I need to make a device that can give me 48x magnification of nearby objects.

Can someone guide me on how to practically approach this problem, i need to be able to take pictures of this 48x zoomed in object?
What kind of lens arrangement can get me this magnification?

I tried searching for single convex lenses that can give me such magnification but even for a 10x magnification, the diameter of lenses were too small.

the whole device should not be more than 15 cm long

Comment: "*the diameter of lenses were too small* One thing about asking good questions is to provide all the details. Notice that when you said this, you never said how large was large enough or how small was too small. It's about as useful as saying have said you have a problem and then not telling anyone what the problem actually was. Frankly, it sounds like you're in over your head anyways. Better to just buy a trinocular microscope where you can equip a camera, even if you just buy the head and build the stand yourself. Or a USB microscope.

Comment: An inexpensive microscope can be purchased for ~U$150, or additional lenses can be found for 1/4 that much: https://www.aliexpress.us/item/3256804192883267.html?pdp_npi=2%40dis%21CAD%21C%24%2073.04%21C%24%2062.08%21%21%21%21%21%402101f6b616694768658493383e1a82%2112000028971113080%21btf&_t=pvid%3Ac007ba62-b6d4-40f7-874e-abaa4b502425&afTraceInfo=1005004379198019__pc__pcBridgePPC__xxxxxx__1669476866&spm=a2g0o.ppclist.product.mainProduct&gatewayAdapt=glo2usa4itemAdapt&_randl_shipto=US - it will be better than trying to build your own.

Comment: Standard macroscopes generally go from 5X to 40X ( zoom or turret) and should work much better than any amature construction. You may find one as small as 15 cm. They will have standard ports for cameras.

Comment: The diameters were in the range of millimeters, but i need to be able to place a mobile camera over it and take pictures, i know we can buy such portable devices but i have to make them as part of my project, how do i start?

Comment: I would say you need to change the scope of your project since optics is complicated enough that it can't be a side aspect of a project when you have no knowledge on optics. And if the optics is the main part of your project then you're going to need to read up because lenses have all sorts of strange parameters and you can't just randomly stack up a set of lenses and have it work properly. At least that's what I gather every time I need a bit of optics and start veering into it. It's always been enough to put a stop to things. That was just me trying to get one lens, not a stack.

Comment: If you're desperate I suppose you could go and buy a couple of microscope eye pieces and barlow lenses off Amazon and stack them onto each other at various distances to see what happens. Or two eyeloupes. If it does what you want then you can break the lenses out the loupe frame and mount it yourself.